# react conditional rendering with design pattern

Tags: reactjs, react-native, design-patterns, software-design

My question is, what would be the best way to set up the conditional rendering in this code to keep the code scalable and maintainable? i mean in a render function. i would like in future when i add new component,i do not want to touch the old code to add the new component. any ideas? i already know about

{this.state.state1?Component/>:null}

```
import * as React from "react";
import LoginForm from "./forms/LoginForm";
import MenuForm from "./forms/MenuForm";
import HomeForm from "./forms/HomeForm";
import TermsForm from "./forms/TermsForm";
import IdentificationResultForm from "./forms/IdentificationResultForm";
import CompanyForm from "./forms/CompanyForm";
import handleAppDateInputFromClient from "../api/azureController.js";
import ListViewForm from "./forms/ListViewForm";
import PartDetails from "./forms/PartDetails";
import ThemeForm from "./forms/ThemeForm";

export default class TemplateController extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flowComponentNumber: 0,
    };
    this.config = {};
    this.translation = {};
  }

  handelSubmit = (companyName) => {
    // call azure controller with companyName and config
    handleAppDateInputFromClient(companyName, this.config);
    console.log(companyName, this.config);
    this.handleFlowComponent();
  };

  handleLanguage = (key, value) => {
    this.translation[key] = value;
  };

  handleChildSubmit = (key, value) => {
    this.config[key] = value;
    console.log(this.config);
    this.handleFlowComponent();
  };

  handleFlowComponent = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      flowComponentNumber: prevState.flowComponentNumber + 1,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    let component;
    // let next = <Button variant="primary" type="button" onClick={this.handleFlowComponent}></Button>

    if (this.state.flowComponentNumber === 0) {
      component = <LoginForm now={10} handler={this.handleChildSubmit} />;
    } else if (this.state.flowComponentNumber === 1) {
      component = <HomeForm now={20} handler={this.handleChildSubmit} />;
    } else if (this.state.flowComponentNumber === 2) {
      component = <TermsForm now={30} handler={this.handleChildSubmit} />;
    } else if (this.state.flowComponentNumber === 3) {
      component = <IdentificationResultForm now={40} handler={this.handleChildSubmit} />;
    } else if (this.state.flowComponentNumber === 4) {
      component = <MenuForm now={50} handler={this.handleChildSubmit} />;
    } else if (this.state.flowComponentNumber === 5) {
      component = (
        <ListViewForm
          now={60}
          handler={this.handleChildSubmit}
          languageHandler={this.handleLanguage}
        />
      );
    } else if (this.state.flowComponentNumber == 6) {
      component = (
        <PartDetails
          now={70}
          handler={this.handleChildSubmit}
          languageHandler={this.handleLanguage}
        />
      );
    } else if (this.state.flowComponentNumber === 7) {
      component = <ThemeForm now={80} handler={this.handleChildSubmit} />;
    } else if (this.state.flowComponentNumber === 8) {
      component = <CompanyForm now={90} handler={this.handelSubmit} />;
    } else if (this.state.flowComponentNumber === 9) {
      component = <h1 style={{ color: "greenyellow" }}> Your submit is successful </h1>;
    }

    return <>{component}</>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe an array prop that has render prop functions for each `flowComponentNumber`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. could u pls explain more?. but array means that i will need to change it if any component has added

Comment: Well, of course, but you'd only need to change the array, not the component itself.